# JSON Object Returns Null

Tags: java, json

I have a very strange error when trying to get a number from a JSON API; the object seems to be null, although the URL (and code) should be correct.

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["success"] not found.
```

I have tried printing out the JSONObject, and it gives me this:

```
{}
```

Here is my code:

```
    try{
        String url = "https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=1&type=uint16";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new URL(url).openStream());
        String resultType = jsonObject.getString("success");
        if(resultType.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            int number = jsonArray.getInt(0);
           //do stuff with number
        }
        else{
            //unsuccessful
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       //handle catch
    }
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? I'm asking because I can't seem to find a library with a `JSONObject` constructor that takes an `InputStream` as a parameter.

Comment: @Andreas Quite honestly I'm not too sure, but the imports I am using are import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: @Arraying No additional Libraries? Are these JDK classes? Seems wierd to me

Comment: Seems you're calling this constructor: [`JSONObject(java.lang.Object bean)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-). Since the `InputStream` returned by `openStream()` (which you need to close too, or you have a memory leak), and since it has no "bean" getters, you end up with an empty JSON object. In short, you're calling it wrong, i.e. not actually giving it the JSON string.

Comment: @n247s Well I haven't manually added anything, it would seem as if they are JDK classes, but I do have Apache Commons added to my dependencies.

Comment: @Arraying Do you have a sample JSON format, how it looks like ?

Comment: @javaguy If you open the URL shown in the code, you get this response: `{"type":"uint16","length":1,"data":[5430],"success":true}`

Comment: @Arraying if you haven't added any Libraries, you might be using classes from the non-public API. In general not a good idea. Please consider taking a look at Json libraries (a quick google search will do).

Comment: You need to read (consume) the content returned by the `openStream()` yourself, as a `String`. The `JSONObject` class will not do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andreas is right, add this piece of code in your try block to convert input stream into a json string  -

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
int ch;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((ch = is.read()) != -1)
sb.append((char)ch);            
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I've used the following yet it still gives me the same error:

Comment: make sure to pass sb.toString() in your JsonObject constructor

Comment: Still doesn't work, I even copied and pasted the code, still errors.